# Clear EditText before reading barcode?

Tags: java, android, barcode, handheld

how can I delete the contents of an edit text before reading a barcode with the laser handheld. The problem is that when I am in the `setOnKeyListener`, it has already been read. This is why I can not delete the contents of edittext at this point in the code.

I would need to understand how to delete the text every time a barcode is read without touching any buttons.

```
mBinding.barcode.setOnKeyListener((View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                presenter.handleBarcode(mBinding.barcode.getText().toString().trim());
            }
            return true;
        });
```

This is handleBarcode method:

```
 public void handleBarcode(String barcode) {
    boolean hasResult = false;
    for (Product product : mProducts) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(product.getBarcode()) && product.getBarcode().equals(barcode)) {

            hasResult = true;

            if (product.getQuantita_eff() < product.getQuantita_prev()) {
                /* --------- GESTIONE DEL NUMERO DI COLLI PER ARTICOLO ----------*/
                if (mNroColliMap.containsKey(product.getBarcode())) {
                    mNroColliMap.put(product.getBarcode(), mNroColliMap.get(product.getBarcode()) + 1);
                } else {
                    mNroColliMap.put(product.getBarcode(), 1);
                }
                /* --------- FINE GESTIONE DEL NUMERO DI COLLI PER ARTICOLO ----------*/

                //Controllo se sono stati letti tutti i colli (attualmente basta rileggere lo stesso codice)
                if (mNroColliMap.get(product.getBarcode()) == product.getNro_colli()) {
                    product.setQuantita_eff(product.getQuantita_eff() + 1);
                    product.setDt_lettura_barcode(Utils.formatDateTime(new Date()));
                    product.setStatus(Product.Status.DONE);

                    /* --------- CONTROLLO DATA CONSEGNA TASS E NUMERO COLLI ----------*/
                    if (!product.getData_consegna_tassativa().equals(" ")) {
                        getView().showError("Questo articolo ha data di consegna tassativa il " + product.getData_consegna_tassativa());
                    }
                    /* --------- FINE CONTROLLO DATA CONSEGNA TASS E NUMERO COLLI ----------*/

                    registerDisposable(Completable
                            .fromAction(() -> getStorage().getDb().products().update(product))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(() -> {
                                getView().notifyProductAdded(product, null);

                                int missingItems = product.getQuantita_prev() - product.getQuantita_eff();
                                if (missingItems > 0) {
                                    getView().notifyMissingItemsForProduct(product, missingItems);
                                }

                                if (!getView().isScannerEnable()) {
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> getView().enableScanner(true), 2000);
                                }
                            }, throwable -> getView().enableScanner(true)));
                } else {
                    mNroColliMap.put(product.getBarcode(), mNroColliMap.get(product.getBarcode()) + 1);
                }
            } else {
                getView().notifyProductAlreadyScanned();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasResult) {
        getContractorForBarcodeVerification(barcode);
    }
}
```

Comment: how you fire up barcode scanner ? You have any dedicated button for it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Inside the method `handleBarcode(..)` you can write:

```
mBinding.barcode.clear()
```

This will clear the text each time you scan the barcode without any touches.

Let's hope this will get you what you want.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
public void handleBarcode(EditText edittext, String barcode) {
```

Then,

```
    mBinding.barcode.setOnKeyListener((View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) -> {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            presenter.handleBarcode(mBinding.barcode, mBinding.barcode.getText().toString().trim());
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Finally, `edittext.clear()`

Try it.

Comment: I would like that at every reading the previous text was removed without touching anything, the keyboard is not even visible

Comment: can you show the method contents of: `handleBarcode(..)`

Comment: The method handleBarcode is in Presenter class instead the mBinding is in the main activity so i can't clear the edit text in the presenter i guess

Comment: You need to get the `Edittext` object in the Presenter class. What are the params in `handleBarcode()` in Presenter class? @Erik Can you show the signature of it?

Comment: Edited. I can't pass the params into the handleBarcode because i use this method in two different situation and only in one of the two cases I need it

Comment: @Erik, Check the solution now